# how to create reverse routes with react-router

Tags: javascript, react-router

I'm wondering if there is a recommended way to construct URLs for my links in my `react-router` based app. In the world of `Zend Framework` for `php`, I'd be using a url helper which used reverse routes. I'd feed in my route name and params to a route config, and it would spit out the URL that I'd link to (or push to in the case of `react-router`).

I found [this](https://github.com/ngokevin/react-router-reverse): but it looks like it only supports up to version 1 of `react-router`. I'm on version 3.

Comment: it existed  in (very very) early versions but has been later wiped out. anybody who gets here by searching and asks the same question may follow teh drama starting from therad https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/1514 and all follow-up discussions.

Answer (score 7):

With same intention I've finished up using `generatePath` from 'react-router-dom' package.

E.g. `projects/routes.js` contains config:

```
import {generatePath} from "react-router-dom";

export const EDIT = {
    route: "/projects/:id",
    generate(id) {
        return generatePath(this.route, {id})
    }
}
```

And `<Route>` relies on `.route` part:

```
<Route path={ProjectRoutes.EDIT.route} component={ProjectEdit} />
```

While `<Link>` relies on `.generate()`

```
<Link to={ProjectRoutes.EDIT.generate(someVariable.id)}>Edit me!</Link>
```

It's definitely not reversing by name. But I found this approach more predictable and flexible since there are no chances to run into name conflict.